# Unit templates and non-template destination units

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer, systemd-unit

I like to keep my custom unit files in their own directory away from /etc. In 247 this worked well, using something like the following:

`systemctl enable /path/to/unit.service`

This also worked with templates, even those that had an associated timer:

`systemctl enable /path/to/timed-unit@.*`

After which you would instantiate:

`systemctl enable timed-unit@instance.timer`

However in 252 when trying to enable the files using pathnames, I now get the following errors:

`Failed to enable unit: Destination unit timers.target is a non-template unit.`

or:

`Failed to enable unit: Destination unit multi-user.target is a non-template unit.`

The docs[1] indicate that if a template lists a service (in this case via `WantedBy`s), then it needs a `DefaultInstance` or instance provided on enabling. This kind of makes sense, so either the behaviour has been tightened up, or a bug has been fixed in 252.

However providing an instance to the path results in a file not found error (as would be expected). I could probably create the symlinks myself, but is there any way to have systemd register a unit file on the filesystem to be enabled with an instance later?

[1] https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#%5BInstall%5D%20Section%20Options

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the templated units on the filesystem *do* register, but the error message/output has changed and doesn't confirm so.

So enabling an instance after works as it did before.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you should not be able to enable template units, only instance units should be able to be enabled.
Because the template itself is not a real unit that can be started on it's self.

You could instead of enabling the template units, which i think you do just so systemd can find the real files by creating symlinks in `/etc`, try the `systemctl link` command which is meant especially for that purpose...